Why is the time derivative of the wavefunction proportional to a linear operator on it?
I am currently trying to self-study quantum mechanics. From what I have read, it is said that knowing the wave function at some instant determines its behavior at all feature instants, I came across an explanantion that the Schrödinger equation is the reason, however, in the book by Landau & Lifshitz,  they made this argument before developing (or introducing) that equation (see picture attached). I would like to know whether its an assumption or not and also why they deduce that the partial time derivative must equal some linear operator acting on the wave function.


Related: Why can't $ i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ be considered the Hamiltonian operator? and links therein.

Does this answer your question? Why can't $ i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ be considered the Hamiltonian operator?

In the text you have pasted, they are not really making arguments, derivations or assumptions, they are making statements:

The wave function determines the quantum state at all times. This can be considered a consequence of the Schrodinger equation as you point out, but here they are simply stating it as a true fact about quantum mechanics.
By the principle of superposition, the relation between the time derivative and the wave function must be linear. This simply a restatement of the superposition principle, which it is stated holds for wave functions. Consider the wave function $\Psi = \psi_1 + \psi_2$. The evolution of $\Psi$ is the sum of the independent evolutions of $\psi_1$ and $ \psi_2$, so $\partial_t \Psi = \partial_t \psi_1 + \partial_t \psi_2$. The only operator for which $O(\Psi) = O(\psi_1)+O(\psi_2)$ always holds is a linear operator.


If I can remember well, Landau and Lifschitz first introduce the probabilistic interpretation of the wave function, being
$$\rho(\mathbf{r},t) = \psi(\mathbf{r},t)^* \psi(\mathbf{r},t) \ ,$$
so that normalization condition holds
$$1 = \int_{\mathbf{r} \in V} \psi(\mathbf{r},t)^* \psi(\mathbf{r},t) = \langle\psi(t) | \psi(t) \rangle $$
the probability density of the coordinates.
Now,

if we trust the superposition observed in nature the equation must be linear, and thus the equation must be of the form

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}{|\psi \rangle} = \hat{L} |\psi \rangle$$

if we trust (since there is an experimental evidence) the probabilistic interpretation of the wave function, and the fact that normalization holds at every time $t$, the operator of the linear equation must have the form $\hat{L} = -i c \hat{H}$, being $c = \frac{1}{\hbar}$ a constant involving Planck's constant, and $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian operator, in order to match the experimental results. You can recover classical mechanics as well, as an example looking for Ehrenfest theorem.
The solution of the Schrodinger equation
$$|\dot{\psi} \rangle = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H} | \psi \rangle$$
reads (if the Hamiltonian is independent from time)
$$|\psi (t) \rangle = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} t} | \psi(0) \rangle \ ,$$
being $ e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} t}$ the unitary evolution operator, and the normalization condition always satisfied, if it holds at the initial time,
$$\langle \psi(t) | \psi(t) \rangle = \langle e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} t}\psi(0) | e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} t} \psi(0) \rangle = \langle \psi(0) | \underbrace{e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} t} e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} t}}_{=1} \psi(0) \rangle = \langle \psi(0) | \psi(0) \rangle= 1 \ .$$


Remarks. In the latter expression, the fact that the Hamiltonian operator is self-adjoint has been used.
The unitary operator can be interpreted with a series expansion,
$$e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H}t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} \right)^k}{k!} \ ,$$
and written in a "diagonal form" in the base of stationary states (here meant to be discrete), i.e. the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian as
$$\begin{aligned} e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H}t} & = \underbrace{|\psi_a\rangle \langle \psi_a}_{\hat{I}} | e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H}t} \underbrace{|\psi_b\rangle \langle \psi_b |}_{=\hat{I}} = \\
& = \psi_a\rangle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \langle \psi_a | \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat{H} \right)^k}{k!} |\psi_b\rangle  \langle \psi_b | = \\
& = \psi_a\rangle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_b\right)^k}{k!}}_{e^{-i \frac{E_b}{\hbar}t}}  \underbrace{\langle \psi_a |\psi_b\rangle}_{=\delta_{ab}}  \langle \psi_b | = \\
& = | \psi_a \rangle \langle \psi_a | e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_a t} \ .
\end{aligned}$$
